# Apache Limit: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit

Tags: apache, server, configuration, limit

My server has 32 cores and 128G of RAM.

The site keeps crashing and I'm seeing this error in the logs: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.

Here is my current Apache config:

```
MaxKeepAliveRequests    400
KeepAliveTimeout        5
Timeout                 300

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    ServerLimit                             32
    StartServers                            8
    MinSpareThreads                         50
    MaxSpareThreads                         400
    ThreadsPerChild                         50
    MaxRequestWorkers                       10000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild                  6000
    GracefulShutdownTimeout                 30
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So... did you increase ServerLimit?

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be a known bug in Apache, which was solved in Apache 2.4.25. However, having said that, I think there's specific reason behind this. Calculate the thrashing point of your server and fine-tune the directives.

For example, `MaxRequestWorkers` should be `ServerLimit` times `ThreadsPerChild`. Yours doesn't reflect this rule.

I have 7 individual nodes for an application. For some reason, one is running on mpm event and others are worker. One day at an exact second, all of those 6 servers got the `scoreboard is full` error, but the one with mpm event didn't. Later, I changed all those to event and it's been working fine since then. Obviously I made some changes to the configuration as well.

Comment: I'm running Apache 2.4.57 and still facing this issue